# Laravel Sentry registering user even though group is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

The problem is, is that Sentry is still registering the user even though the specified group does not exist.

```
if(Request::isMethod('post'))
{

    $validation = Validator::make([
            'username'  =>  Input::get('username'),
            'password'  =>  Input::get('password'),
            'password_confirmation' =>  Input::get('password_confirmation')
        ],
        [
            'username'  =>  'unique:users,username|required',
            'password'  =>  'same:password_confirmation|required'
        ]);

    if($validation->fails())
        return Redirect::route('addUser')
            ->withErrors($validation->getMessageBag())
            ->withInput(Input::except(['password', 'password_confirmation']));
    else
    {
        /** Do sentry stuff */
        try
        {
            $activated = Input::get('activated') ? true : false;

            // Create the user
            $user = Sentry::createUser(array(
                'username'  =>  Input::get('username'),
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password'),
                'activated' => $activated,
            ));

            $group = Sentry::findGroupById(Input::get('group'));
            $user->addGroup($group);
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e)
        {
            $message[] = 'Login field is required.';
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e)
        {
            $message[] = 'Password field is required.';
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserExistsException $e)
        {
            $message[] = 'User with this login already exists.';
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e)
        {
            $message[] = 'Group was not found.';
        }



        if(isset($message))
            return Redirect::route('addUser')
                ->withErrors($message)
                ->withInput(Input::except(['password', 'password_confirmation']));
        else
        {
            $message = 'User has been added';
            return Redirect::route('addUser')
                ->with('success', $message);
        }
    }
}
return $this->render('admin/users/add');
```

Now, as the exception is thrown I would have assumed the user would not be created, however I can't figure out why it is.

Is there a specific way or another way that I am missing in which to only register the user if no exceptions are thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The user has to exist and have an id for Sentry to attempt to add the group.  My suggestion would be to break it out into 2 try / catch blocks:  One for adding the user, and one for adding the user to a group, then...

```
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e)
    {
        $message[] = 'Group was not found.';
        $user->delete();
    }
```